# Calculating number of business days between 2 dates in SAS,

Tags: sas

```
Member  StartDate   EndDate
1   27-Jul-17   27-Oct-17
2   27-Aug-19   11-Sep-19
3   28-Mar-17   31-Jul-17
4   17-Jun-19   13-Aug-19
5   21-Mar-17   16-May-17
6   17-Mar-17   05-Jul-17
7   20-Jan-16   11-Apr-16
8   27-Apr-15   09-Jun-15
9   13-Feb-19   19-Mar-19
10  27-May-15   30-Sep-15
11  16-Dec-16   30-Mar-17
12  17-Nov-16   02-Feb-17
data mydata;
set mdata;
weekdays=intck("weekdays",startdate,enddate);
run;

Holiday data is here:
holiday_date    description 
01/01/2003  New Years Day           
17/02/2003  Family Day              
18/04/2003  Good Friday             
21/04/2003  Easter Monday           
19/05/2003  Victoria Day            
01/07/2003  Canada Day              
04/08/2003  Civic Holiday           
01/09/2003  Labour Day              
13/10/2003  Thanksgiving Day        
11/11/2003  Remembrance Day         
25/12/2003  Christmas Day (*)       
26/12/2003  Boxing Day (*)          
01/01/2004  New Years Day           
16/02/2004  Family Day              
09/04/2004  Good Friday             
12/04/2004  Easter Monday           
24/05/2004  Victoria Day            
01/07/2004  Canada Day              
02/08/2004  Civic Holiday
```

I want to calculate number of week days excluding holidays. I have a table with the holidays dates. How do I apply it for each record to calculate business days?

Comment: I want to exclude the holidays and weekends so that I only have business days

Answer (score 0):

This example is copied from SAS documentation.
Example 3: Using Custom Intervals with the INTCK Function

```
options intervalds=(BankingDays=BankDayDS);
data BankDayDS(keep=begin);
   start = '15DEC1998'd;
   stop  = '15JAN2002'd;
   nwkdays = intck('weekday',start,stop);
   do i = 0 to nwkdays;
      begin = intnx('weekday',start,i);
      year = year(begin);
      if begin ne holiday('NEWYEAR',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('MLK',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('USPRESIDENTS',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('MEMORIAL',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('USINDEPENDENCE',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('LABOR',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('COLUMBUS',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('VETERANS',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('THANKSGIVING',year) and 
         begin ne holiday('CHRISTMAS',year) then
      output;
   end;
   format begin date9.;
run;
data CountDays;
   start = '01JAN1999'd;
   stop  = '31DEC2001'd;
   ActualDays = intck('DAYS',start,stop);
   Weekdays   = intck('WEEKDAYS',start,stop);
   BankDays   = intck('BankingDays',start,stop);
   format start stop date9.;
run;

title 'Methods of Counting Days';

proc print data=CountDays;
run;
```

[image]

In response to the comment.

```
data mydata;
   input Member (StartDate EndDate)(:date.);
       format startdate enddate date11.;
       cards;
    1   27-Jul-17   27-Oct-17
    2   27-Aug-19   11-Sep-19
    3   28-Mar-17   31-Jul-17
    4   17-Jun-19   13-Aug-19
    5   21-Mar-17   16-May-17
    6   17-Mar-17   05-Jul-17
    7   20-Jan-16   11-Apr-16
    8   27-Apr-15   09-Jun-15
    9   13-Feb-19   19-Mar-19
    10  27-May-15   30-Sep-15
    11  16-Dec-16   30-Mar-17
    12  17-Nov-16   02-Feb-17
    ;;;;
       run;
    proc print;
       run;
    proc summary data=mydata nway missing;
       output out=range(drop=_:) min(startdate)=start max(enddate)=stop;
       run;
    proc print;
       run;
    options intervalds=(BankingDays=BankDayDS);
    data BankDayDS(keep=begin);
       set range;
       nwkdays = intck('weekday',start,stop);
       do i = 0 to nwkdays;
          begin = intnx('weekday',start,i);
          year = year(begin);
          if begin ne holiday('NEWYEAR',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('MLK',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('USPRESIDENTS',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('MEMORIAL',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('USINDEPENDENCE',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('LABOR',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('COLUMBUS',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('VETERANS',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('THANKSGIVING',year) and 
             begin ne holiday('CHRISTMAS',year) then
          output;
       end;
       format begin date9.;
    run;
    
    data mydata;
       set mydata;
       ActualDays  = intck('DAYS',startdate,enddate);
       weekdays    = intck("weekdays",startdate,enddate);
       BankDays    = intck('BankingDays',startdate,enddate);
       run;
    
    title 'Methods of Counting Days';
    proc print data=mydata;
       run;
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that method prior to asking here but how do I apply that in the data above? Could you add that script into the data above to calculate number of business days for each record from startdate to enddate?

Comment: Hi @ken I added a bit to the end of my answer that might be helpful.  Also Good Friday is holiday('EASTER',2020)-2;

Comment: Yes, this is very helpful. However, I need to include holidays in Canada and it seems they are not part of the keyword for holidays. I have table with holidays partly referenced in my original request, how do I replace that with what you have for holidays? Thanks so much!

Comment: @ken look at the documentation for the holiday function.  Canada day, Canada thanksgiving etc.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out but just like you said, Easter Friday and Monday are holidays and not part of the holidays noted in the documentation. They should include all possible holidays and analysts can leave out those holidays not observed in the country or state within the query.

Comment: Just put the holidays in a table(SAS data set) and use your method of choice to lookup the holiday.

Comment: I’m an intermediate sas analyst but not a programmer. Is there by any chance you can write for me a basic query with maybe even 5 holidays which I can use to replace the sas holiday query based on the holiday list from my original question. I already have a data with holidays updated annually.